# Reassign a variable with a random number upon meeting condition (vanilla Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how to generate a new random number once the condition of the if statement is met. Once the length of the array reaches 3, reassign the "randomNumber" variable a new number. As of now I don't see any changes when the randomNumber variable is logged to the console and the condition is met, the number doesn't change without refreshing the page.

```js
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

console.log(randomNumber);

const numberArr = [];

const form1 = document.getElementById("form1");

if (numberArr.length === 3) {
        numberArr.splice(0, 3);
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
};

form1.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    const values = document.getElementsByName("number")[0].value;
    numberArr.push(values);
    e.preventDefault();
    form1.reset();
});
```

```html
          <form id="form1">

                <div class="row w-100 d-flex justify-content-between div1">

                    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <input type="number" name="number" id="number" min="1" max="100">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <button type="submit" form="form1" id="sub1">Submit</button>
                    </div>

                </div>

        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code you have written checks if the array has 3 elements on **page load** which is never the case, and doesnt rerun later. So in order to fix this just put the if statement inside the event listener and it should work as you expected.

```js
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

console.log(randomNumber);

const numberArr = [];

const form1 = document.getElementById("form1");

form1.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    const values = document.getElementsByName("number")[0].value;
    numberArr.push(values);
    e.preventDefault();
    if (numberArr.length === 3) {
        numberArr.splice(0, 3);
        randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        console.log(randomNumber);
       };
    form1.reset();
});
```

```html
<form id="form1">

                <div class="row w-100 d-flex justify-content-between div1">

                    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                            <input type="number" name="number" id="number" min="1" max="100">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <button type="submit" form="form1" id="sub1">Submit</button>
                    </div>

                </div>

        </form>
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not reassign the original variable with a new random number

Comment: updated the code could you check?

Comment: It looks it does generate a new random number but can this number be used again in my code? If I take the original variable and use it again it will show as changed? that might not make any sense sorry

Comment: yeah it can be used again in your code

Comment: This was a dumb question I had already done that in my other code, I just simplified it when I wrote it on here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're not checking the condition each time the user submits the form, but only once in the page scope (when the page is loading).

```js
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
console.log(randomNumber);

const numberArr = [];

const form1 = document.getElementById("form1");
form1.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  
  const values = document.getElementsByName("number")[0].value;
  numberArr.push(values);
  form1.reset();
  
  if (numberArr.length === 3) {
    numberArr.splice(0, 3);
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        console.log(randomNumber);
  }
});
```

```html
  <form id="form1">
    <div class="row w-100 d-flex justify-content-between div1">
      <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <input type="number" name="number" id="number" min="1" max="100">
      </div>
      <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button type="submit" form="form1" id="sub1">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Also, `numberArr` doesn't make sense in this code, cause you can use a simple counter and increase it by 1 each time the form is submitted, and reset it after the
condition is met.

Comment: Sorry yours actually worked. It was my mistake. I had actually already done this in my code before I simplified it to add it to the stackoverflow but I wasn't considering scope when I added it here

Answer (score 0):

Check within the handler function (so: every time the button is clicked). Here's a simplified snippet, using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, handle);
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
console.log(`initial ${randomNumber}`);
let numberArr = [];

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.id === `sub1`) {
    numberArr.push(+document.querySelector(`#number`).value ?? 0);
    const len = numberArr.length;
    if (numberArr.length === 3) {
      randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
      numberArr = [];
    }
    return console.log(randomNumber);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row w-100 d-flex justify-content-between div1">

  <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <input type="number" name="number" id="number" min="1" max="100">
  </div>

  <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <button type="submit" form="form1" id="sub1">Submit</button>
  </div>

</div>
```